# Is it possible to set cmake flags for conan required libraries?

Tags: cmake, tcp, amqp, conan

I am trying to set the `-DAMQP-CPP_LINUX_TCP=ON` cmake flag for `amqp-cpp/4.3.26`, a required library in my conanfile. Is it possible to set cmake flags for required libraries via conan? If so, how?

I have looked through a lot of the conan center documentation, with no luck so far.

Comment: You can inject compile flags via ``tools.build:cxxflags`` conf, for example, but that seems it is not a compile flag? Is it a preprocessor definition or a CMake variable? If preprocessor definition, you can try ``tools.build:defines``. If CMake variable, you can inject a toolchain: https://docs.conan.io/2/examples/tools/cmake/cmake_toolchain/inject_cmake_variables.html

Comment: ConanCenter documentation will typically not explain those things, but the Conan tools docs: https://docs.conan.io. In any case, it doesn't look great injecting flags in the general case, better look for options in the ``amqp-cpp`` package, in this case it seems it contains a ``linux_tcp_module`` option. So ``conan ... -o amqp-cpp*:linux_tcp_module=True``